# Restrict airDatepickerInput() to not allow a single date selection

Tags: javascript, r, datepicker, shiny

I'm using `airDatepickerInput()` from the `ShinyWidgets` package.

I have the `range` argument set to `TRUE`, and I'd like to disable the option of selecting only a single date (so either select a range of dates - or get a null value for that input).

Is that even possible?
If not, can you please recommend something similar to the air datepicker (besides `shiny::dateRangeInput`)?

I went over the [documentation](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/) of the original JS library and didn't find a solution.
However I suspect it was possible [in the past](https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/commit/8dbf738ea6415ed049191e00bf9ca66dd8805c5e) and then was changed.

**Minimal working example**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    airDatepickerInput(
      inputId = "timeframe",
      label = "Timeframe",
      value = "2018-06-01", # because it's a single value - it should be changed to NULL
      range = T
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

Edit:
**Screenshot of (only) a single date selected**

[image]

Comment: Why do you initialise with one date and not NULL or a date range? As far as I can tell, you are not able to select one date when using the input widget---so there is no way to actually choose a single date from the interface.

Comment: @AndersEllernBilgrau, I'm initializing with one value only for the example. It doesn't matter if it's initialized with NULL or not. The point is that it's indeed possible to select only a single date (you can try running the minimal example and see).